# How to remove resize parameters from URLs that contains images using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, parameters

I need a Javascript code (no JQuery or anything else) to remove resize parameters from URLs that contain images.

Input:

> http://www.example.com/image-320x180.jpg

Output:

> http://www.example.com/image.jpg

Basically this code should start searching from right to left, first looking for a dot (that one before jpg), then to delete anything until it meets a dash, then stops.

Anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) + [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: If you describe [what you have already tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and why it hasn't worked, your question may get more attention.

Comment: I'm a beginner, and I'm still learning JS. I hope that someone finds a solution. I searched on Stack Overflow, but so far I didn't find exactly what I want, only something quite similar (with parameters mentioned width=x height=y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lastIndexOf:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/image-320x180.jpg";
var lastDash = url.lastIndexOf("-");
var lastDot = url.lastIndexOf(".");
url = url.replace(url.substring(lastDash, lastDot), "");
```